# Check network available in android

Tags: java, android, networking, connectivity

I have to develop one android application.

Here i have to develop one twitter integration android application.

i have using below code:

```
public void onClickTwitt() {
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        Twitt twitt = new Twitt(getActivity(), consumer_key, secret_key);
        twitt.shareToTwitter(_Title);
    } else {
        showToast("No Network Connection Available !!!");
    }
}
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
     ConnectivityManager connectivity =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here am getting below error :

```
The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type 
 SubCate
```

Please help me...How can i resolve these error ????

Comment: the method isNetworkAvailable() is defined inside an Activity?

Comment: pass context like context.getSystemService

Comment: getSystemService is from the Context class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public void onClickTwitt() {
    if (isNetworkAvailable(this)) {
        Twitt twitt = new Twitt(getActivity(), consumer_key, secret_key);
        twitt.shareToTwitter(_Title);
    } else {
        showToast("No Network Connection Available !!!");
    }
}
public boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity =(ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo networkInfo : info) {
            if (networkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
 public static  boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    if(context == null) { return false; }
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    // if no network is available networkInfo will be null, otherwise check if we are connected
    try {
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AppLog.e(TAG, "isNetworkAvailable()" , e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

and then do this

```
if(isNetworkAvailable(TempOrderActivity.this)) {
                //do something

            } else {
                //do something
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this Code and working great, Copied from my App. Hope this will solve your problem

```
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```