# check internet connection and show turn on window if unavailble

Tags: android

```
   private boolean isNetworkConnected() {

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;  
      }
```

i have tried above code but it's not activating mobile data .

i need to check internet connection and show turn on window if internet connection unavailable. how to do that

Comment: Not sure if you can turn on mobile data directly, probably not, but you can show a dialog and send the user to the setting page.

Comment: yes i know i can't turn on mobile data directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this
If you are not connected to Internet you can show an Alert Dialog box and if the user clicks **ENABLE INTERNET** then open the Internet page like below

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("YOU ARE NOT CONNECTED WITH INTERNET")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("ENABLE INTERNET",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                Intent callInternetsettingIntent = new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);

                                startActivity(callInternetsettingIntent);

                            }
                        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }

                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Try this and let me know.

Comment: it works . first i check internet connection and i add this code

Comment: @Rukshanwithanage Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

check this [Check network available in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294607/check-network-available-in-android) 
and add listener on button or something to enable wifi with following code:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

make sure these permission are added to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

try out following code work perfect for my application

//put two method in your Activity file

```
public boolean isMobileDataEnable() 
{
    boolean mobileDataEnabled = false; // Assume disabled
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    try 
    {
        Class cmClass = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
        method.setAccessible(true); // Make the method callable
        // get the setting for "mobile data"
        mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean)method.invoke(cm);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // Some problem accessible private API and do whatever error handling you want here
    }
    return mobileDataEnabled;
} 

public boolean toggleMobileDataConnection(boolean ON)
{
    try 
    {
        //create instance of connectivity manager and get system connectivity service
        final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        //create instance of class and get name of connectivity manager system service class
        final Class conmanClass  = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
        //create instance of field and get mService Declared field 
        final Field iConnectivityManagerField= conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
        //Attempt to set the value of the accessible flag to true
        iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        //create instance of object and get the value of field conman
        final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
        //create instance of class and get the name of iConnectivityManager field
        final Class iConnectivityManagerClass=  Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
        //create instance of method and get declared method and type
        final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod= iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled",Boolean.TYPE);
        //Attempt to set the value of the accessible flag to true
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
        //dynamically invoke the iConnectivityManager object according to your need (true/false)
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, ON);
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    return true;
}
```

//Check your internet connection close or not if close then turn on Mobile Data

```
if(isMobileDataEnable())
{
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
else
{
    toggleMobileDataConnection(true);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Disable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
}
```