# Not able to check internet status while connected with bluetooth tethering in android

Tags: android

I am working on cab booking app.
In all other case I am getting internet status, but I am unable to detect no internet while connected with Bluetooth tethering.

Please any one help me, I'm getting stuck. I need to implement it same like ola and uber app net checking.

I am using below method:

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Activity activity) {

    NetworkInfo networkInfo = ((ConnectivityManager) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();

    Log.d("net", "" + networkInfo);
    // Log.d("net", ""+!networkInfo.isConnected());

    if (networkInfo == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (!networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294607/check-network-available-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

For check internet status while connected with bluetooth tethering as well as internet connectivity including bluetooth pan . Refer this [check Android internet connectivity including bluetooth pan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059519/the-perfect-function-to-check-android-internet-connectivity-including-bluetooth)

I will suggest to refer this link . It will help to solve your problem

Comment: Thanx for replay. let me try.

Comment: try {
          Process p1 = java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 www.google.com");
          int returnVal = p1.waitFor();
          boolean reachable = (returnVal==0);
          return reachable;
      } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return false;

Comment: This method is working fine for me, but please tell me this can i use? and it will not affect.

Comment: Yes you can. It cant  affect.