# Android Detect Network change when Internet is available even when app is closed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I have made a broadcast receiver that Toasts a message on screen when connected to internet. My Code is ->

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
        String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.INTERNET, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE};

        if (!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }
    }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".NetworkChangeReceiver"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
```

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected())
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
       /* if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {


            Toast.makeText(context, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }*/


    }
}
```

However,it works only when application is open.When Application is closed,it doesn't work,how to make this work even when application is closed?

Comment: Use service for that.From the service send the broadcast.

Comment: This happens usually in some device. I have Mi device and I was facing the same problem.
I just resolved this problem to add my application in auto-start list from setting of my phone.

Answer (score 2):

First of all declare your receiver to Menifest file,

```
    <receiver android:name=".services.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver.java

```
public class ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static final String CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_ACTION = "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            //check internet connection
            if (!ConnectionHelper.isConnectedOrConnecting(context)) {
                if (context != null) {
                    boolean show = false;
                    if (ConnectionHelper.lastNoConnectionTs == -1) {//first time
                        show = true;
                        ConnectionHelper.lastNoConnectionTs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    } else {
                        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - ConnectionHelper.lastNoConnectionTs > 1000) {
                            show = true;
                            ConnectionHelper.lastNoConnectionTs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        }
                    }

                    if (show && ConnectionHelper.isOnline) {
                        ConnectionHelper.isOnline = false;
                        context.stopService(new Intent(context, SyncData.class));
                        Log.e("Connection lost.");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Connected.");
                // Perform your actions here
                ConnectionHelper.isOnline = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ConnectionHelper.java

```
public class ConnectionHelper {

    public static long lastNoConnectionTs = -1;
    public static boolean isOnline = true;

    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
    }

    public static boolean isConnectedOrConnecting(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }

}
```

Comment: ConnectionHelper class??

Comment: May b i forgot to include, please check the answer now

Comment: can't find syncdata.class....does this work when app is closed....service is the only solution to such problem i guess...since it can only run in background

Comment: yes, it runs even if app is closed, you can find logs in logcat when app is closed... syncdata is my function that i wanted to perform while device is in network connection, you can replace the function with your actions..

Comment: doesn't work....when app is closed....works when app is open or minimized....when app is closed by sliding from recent tabs,it doesn't work

Comment: the same code works for me, even i tried in a switched off device, as soon as i switched it on and device connected to internet, i got a log printed.

Comment: please check logs from this link, https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4y9ZdZezhtfUEdEWlNSVG1RMmc

the same time i tried switching internet on and off.... recent app pool was empty too. check that out, mate.

Comment: i replaced these lines context.stopService(new Intent(context, SyncData.class));
                        Log.e("Connection lost."); with  Toast.makeText(context,"connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.e("mh","sss"); .....this won't affect the result?

Comment: the log class u r using is android.util.log??

Comment: Yes, Delete those lines regarding SyncData, but keep in mind for closed apps Toast will not be the proper way to track, try logging instead.
You can use any of the logging library or android.util.log

Comment: I started logging using Log.e("msg","connected")......however the logs appear in android studio console when the app is open/minimized and internet is connected or disconnected...no logs appear in android studio console if app is closed by sliding it off the recent apps. PS: I am testing on android M

Comment: dude, I was testing the same for Android N. There is no such issue in logging, the thing is you might have filtered your logcat messages, there might be some type of filter applied. Please check that.

Comment: this is working...thanks....however when i was debugging the app in android studio....the app gave no log/toast/notification upon being closed...however when i removed/detached the cellphone from my computer and then started the app,the receiver worked perfectly fine

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html referring to process lifecycle....A process that is currently executing a BroadcastReceiver (that is, currently running the code in its onReceive(Context, Intent) method) is considered to be a foreground process and will be kept running by the system except under cases of extreme memory pressure.

Once you return from onReceive(), BroadcastReceiver is no longer active. So how is your broadcast receiver working even after it returns from onReceive() method and how it is working even after app is closed?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). You're most recommended to read the documention by Android Studio [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html).

Services will allow a very specific part of your application to survive at all times. Even when the user restart their devices and never run your application again. There is a lot to perceive about Services, but at the moment I believe a snippet will be most helpful to you, here is a little code,

First in your manifest

```
    <!--notification-->
    <service android:name="services.HelloService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:description="My notification Center"/>
    <!--notification-->
```

Second

Create a class called ***HelloService***

and paste the following code inside with the proper imports*

```
public class HelloService extends Service {
private Looper mServiceLooper;
private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

// Handler that receives messages from the thread
 private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
  public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
      super(looper);
  }
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      // Normally we would do some work here, like download a file.
      // For our sample, we just sleep for 5 seconds.
      try {
          Thread.sleep(5000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          // Restore interrupt status.
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      }
      // Stop the service using the startId, so that we don't stop
      // the service in the middle of handling another job
      stopSelf(msg.arg1);
  }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
// Start up the thread running the service.  Note that we create a
// separate thread because the service normally runs in the process's
// main thread, which we don't want to block.  We also make it
// background priority so CPU-intensive work will not disrupt our UI.
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ServiceStartArguments",
        Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
thread.start();

// Get the HandlerThread's Looper and use it for our Handler
mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
  }

  @Override
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "servicestarting",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


  Message msg = mServiceHandler.obtainMessage();
  msg.arg1 = startId;
  mServiceHandler.sendMessage(msg);

  // If we get killed, after returning from here, restart
  return START_STICKY;
      }

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
   // We don't provide binding, so return null
   return null;
          }


 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
   Toast.makeText(this, "service done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
}
```

Inside the 'handleMessage Method' add your bit of code, for example ;

```
  @Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

 //... your bit of code goes here 

  try {
      Thread.sleep(5000);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // Restore interrupt status.
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
  }


    //stopSelf(msg.arg1);
}
```

Lastly, to activate the service class, in your function to trigger the service, first import the HelloService.class, then create an Intent and fire up!

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, HelloService.class);
 startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: *Services will allow a very specific part of your application to survive at all times* that is not true. Nothing survives at "all" times

Comment: well obviously not unless you conditionally kill the service or force shut down the app using a smart manager, else the service will survive at all times.

Comment: The os can kill a service at any time if it needs to free up memory

Comment: That's not entirely accurate. One way is to force your service and override the operating system conditions, the service will remain alive, regardless of memory efficiency.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you speak of. Can you point me to the documentation about that?

Comment: @AlexanderToman read https://medium.com/google-developers/who-lives-and-who-dies-process-priorities-on-android-cb151f39044f#.r97280zhb

Comment: @AlexanderToman I have some data stored in my sqlite database,i need to send it to server when internet is available...so how will i check if internet is available using this service...if i start your service,how will i check if internet is available,.....i need to upload data when server is available...how will i check for network availabilty using this service?

Comment: @PrateekRatnaker simple, refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16294607/check-network-available-in-android

Comment: @AlexanderToman so i should start a service that checks if internet is available and whenever internet is available,i should extract data from sqlite database and send it to server...right??.......broadcast receivers aren't required here right?

Comment: @PrateekRatnaker that should make it work. A broadcast receiver, from it's name, is nothing but a receiver. You're looking for a service. Try it out, and let us know how did it go.

Comment: @AlexanderToman i am trying it out with just service.....service would check continuosly if internet is available,and if it available,i would upload the data to server,.....is this the right approach?....no broadcast receivers would be required

Comment: @PrateekRatnaker yes, go ahead and give it a trial and report the result